# Python: Creating Pie chart with column values from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create a pie chart with column values from a CSV file, but I don't seem to be going the right way with it. I am using a CSV file (student_grades.csv) and I want to create a pie chart with data from the 'Result' column in the csv file. The rows with '1s' in that column mean 'pass', while the rows with '0s' in that column mean 'fail'. I am trying to create a pie chart for pass and fail results. here is what I have done so far, and I will really appreciate and advice please.

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

doc = pd.read_csv('student_grades.csv')

pass_fail_result = doc['Result']
pass_result = []
fail_result = []

plt.pie(str(pass_fail_result))

plt.show()```

This is the csv file that I am using.
```Name,Gender,Attendance,Department,Result
Gabby Smith,Female,Yes,Engineering,1
Dan Jones,Male,Yes,Engineering,1
Benard Clark,Male,Yes,Engineering,0
Lizzy Ringgs,Female,Yes,Engineering,1
Derick H. Leo,Male,Yes,Engineering,0
Matt Dickson,Male,Yes,Engineering,1
Laura Wlliamson,Female,Yes,Engineering,1
Frank A. Mitt,Male,Yes,Engineering,0
Ahmed Hussaini,Male,Yes,Engineering,1
Claire Greg,Female,Yes,Engineering,1
Flora Richards,Female,Yes,Engineering,0
Andy Roy,Male,Yes,Engineering,0
Richard Jones,Male,Yes,Engineering,1
Harry Ben,Male,Yes,Engineering,1
Claudia Green,Female,Yes,Engineering,0
Hamza Yusuf,Male,Yes,Engineering,1
Ella Leonard,Female,Yes,Engineering,0
Patrick Silva,Male,Yes,Engineering,1
````

Answer (score 1):

this will plot # of 1s and # of 0s in a pie chart:

```
plt.pie(doc['Result'].value_counts())
```

to get %:

```
plt.pie(100*df['Result'].value_counts()/len(df))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I can see a pie chart now with two sections, can I make it show the result labels for each area please? This is the code that I have modified now. ```import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

doc = pd.read_csv('student_grades.csv')

pass_fail_result = doc['Result']

print(pass_fail_result)

plt.pie(doc['Result'].value_counts())

plt.pie(100*doc['Result'].value_counts()/len(doc))

plt.show()
```

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html look at labels

Comment: Hello Derek, Thank you very much. I followed the link you sent me and I took time to read the documentation and practice it. Viola! I got it working as I wanted. Once again, thank you.

Comment: not a problem...you can accept the solution if you feel like it answered your question :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys, csv
def doSomething(filePath):
  try:
    with open(filePath, mode='r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in csvreader:
        if (row[2] is "SOMETHING"): # row[2] it's the cvs position

        else: # DO SOMETHING ELSE

  except FileNotFoundError:
    print("[ERROR] Cannot open the file: ", filePath)
```

Comment: Hi Leandro, I am not clear with your advice and code please. Can you go a bit clearer with it? My original code can open the file and when I run it, it just shows the column results and a pie chart. I have modified it and you can see it below please. ```import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

doc = pd.read_csv('student_grades.csv')

pass_fail_result = doc['Result']
pass_result = []
fail_result = []

plt.pie(pass_fail_result)

print(pass_fail_result)

plt.show() ```

Comment: I'm sorry could you please explain yourself clearer? I wrote my explanation about how to access and read values from a CSV file. Of what I see it'd help, but I can't understand your trouble writing the pi char values.

Comment: The situation is this. I want to display a pie chart showing the percentage of pass and fail using the '1s' and '0s' in the column 'Result'. A part of the pie chart will show the percentage of those that passed, and the other part of the chart will show the percentage of those that failed. Rows with '1' mean pass and rows with '0' mean fail. Hope that make sense please.

Comment: Yes, it is clearer. So you have to count the number of times that the 1 or 0 appears and then calculate the percent given the number of numbers you got.

Comment: I did, sorry if my answer didn't feed you up